# Android: How to display named character entities from CDATA elements while parsing with XML DOM parser?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, cdata, domparser

While using the android DOM parser, I'm picking up the following element:

```
<![CDATA[
Widget1&#8230; Widget2&#8230; Widget3&#8230;
]]>
```

I've tried populating a textview using Html.fromHtml as well as trying to shove the contents of that element into a Webview.

both methods display the content, but seems to strip out the named character entities

Anything I can do to retain the formatting/markup?

I am reading the data from an RSS feed if that helps.

this is what my webview instantiation looks like

```
webview.loadData(((Node) nodeList.item(0)).getNodeValue(),  "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently and here's what worked for me.   I used the jsoup.jar from http://jsoup.org/.  Once I added the jar to my project,  I just needed to use the following line:

```
String htmlFreeString = Jsoup.parse( stringWithHtml ). text();
```

Then, I just set the string as the text to my TextView without issue.

Hope that helps.